# java hibernate - cannot find beginTransaction and createQuery

Tags: java, hibernate

I got a problem with the two hibernate methods mentioned in the title, beginTransaction() and createQuery(). Java gives me the cannot find symbol error

This is how I start my session

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil {
 private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

public static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();
    serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            configuration.getProperties()).build();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    return sessionFactory;
}


}
```

and this is how I use the two methods

```
SessionFactory session = HibernateUtil.createSessionFactory();
        Transaction tx = null;
        Users user = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            tx.begin();
            Query query = session.createQuery("FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME='"+userId+"'");
            user = (Users)query.uniqueResult();
            tx.commit();
        }
```

I'm fairly unfamiliar with hibernate and I don't understand why this is happening. I set up my xml config file properly. Netbeans supposedly added all the necessary libraries and I still get the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change this line :

```
SessionFactory session = HibernateUtil.createSessionFactory();
```

to

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.createSessionFactory().openSession();
```

Because `SessionFactory` interface does not implement the `SharedSessionContract` interface which include both

```
getTransaction()
createQuery(String string)
```

methods like `Session`interface does.

And it is good practice to use parameter binding instead of using string concatenation.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME= :userName")
              .setParameter("userName",userId);
```

Comment: thank you this actually fixed my problem but it seems that another problem persists. When I use the getUsername() method from my restful java class it returns null and the authentication fails. Would you know why that might be the case?

Comment: It is better to ask another question with all possible incorrect codes, so that it will be helpful not only to me but also some other person to figure out the exact problem.